# Transforming pandas dataframe into a list of tuples considering index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a structure like this:

```
rowNo | Column 1  | Column 2 | Column 3
0     |   Value   | 123.4    | 1
1     |   Value2  | 111.2    | 3
```

I need to transform it into a list of tuples considering the column `rowNo` as an index, resulting in this structure (`rowNo` starts in `0` but the target list should shift the start to `1`):

```
[(1, ['Value',123.4,1]), (2, ['Value2',111.2,3])]
```

Any inputs are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
out = list(df.assign(rowNo = df['rowNo']+1).set_index('rowNo').agg(list,1).iteritems())
Out[95]: [(1, ['   Value   ', 123.4, 1]), (2, ['   Value2  ', 111.2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some list comprehension with [`* unpacking`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) and [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```py
result = [(rowNo+1, [*rest]) for rowNo, *rest in df.reset_index(drop=True).to_numpy()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
data = list(zip(df.index+1, df.values.tolist()))
```

`OUTPUT`

```
[(1, ['Value', 123.4, 1]), (2, ['Value2', 111.2, 3])]
```